Copying excel sheet rows to another Excel document causes renaming in formula functions that their name ends with numeric characters
I create an excel document with openxml and it produces the document as it was supposed.
Then I want to copy the produced rows in another excel document  that has vba scripts behind and get immediate results.
The problem occurs with the formulas that have functions ending with numeric characters
for example KAP44 below
=@IF(AND((A11 = A10)  (M11 = M10))  T11  KAP44(A11  M11))

(The space characters is because I have turned the windows list separator to space instead of comma)
The above formula is produced from my code and when I copy and paste it to the second excel document with the vba scripts behind, the function name changes like below
=@IF(AND((A11 = A10)  (M11 = M10))  T11  IN44(A11  M11))

So, I think that Excel sees the last 2 numeric characters and thinks that KAP44 is a cell name (and not a fuction) that does not exist and transforms it to a cell name IN44
Any idea about how can I come around this one?

don't really understand what you're doing -- kap44 is a named range in one book but not other?

you could look into INDIRECT

Vagelis, you're right; when you copy and paste the formula manually without VBA, the KAP44 is treated relative reference and thus is changed. You might have already thought about it - if possible prefix your function names with numbers f.ex. with an underscore.

@Excellor how could I use INDIRECT to keep the function name unchanged when copy paste the formula?

@nkalvi the renaming of functions in vba to not end with numeric characters is a solution but for some reasons I prefer to not change the vba scripts

@vagelis, this could be helpful in deciding: Naming and localization for custom functions in Excel - Office Add-ins | Microsoft Learn > A function's name shouldn't be the same as:
Any cells between A1 to XFD1048576 or any cells between R1C1 to R1048576C16384.

@nkalvi yes it is helpfull. So, it is not a choice! Thanks!
